# unable to send request to java servlet from angular 6 httpclient

Tags: java, angular, servlets

how to connect from Angular to java Servlet?
here is my angular service code

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class UploadService {
  url: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = "http://localhost:8081/ServletSample/";
  }

  uploadFile(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.url, data);
  }

  sendData(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.url + "DataServlet", data);
  }
}
```

below is Authservice

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const clonedRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set("X-CustomAuthHeader", "aaaa")
    });
    console.log("req", req);
    console.log("new headers", clonedRequest.headers.keys());

    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }
}
```

java servlet is running in below port

```
http://localhost:8081/ServletSample/DataServlet
```

below is java servlet code

```
package com.test.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DataServlet extends HttpServlet{

      /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 548987777;

    public DataServlet() {
            super();
            System.out.println("DataServlet constructor called");
        }

        /**
         * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
         */
        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
            System.out.println("DataServlet \"Init\" method called"+ config.toString());
        }

        /**
         * @see Servlet#destroy()
         */
        public void destroy() {
            System.out.println("DataServlet \"Destroy\" method called");
        }


        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
        {
            System.out.println("DataServlet doGet method called"+ request);
            doPost(request, response);

        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("DataServlet doPost method called");
        }

}
```

but when i am sending request getting below error in browser console

> **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/ServletSample/DataServlet' from origin 'http://localhost:4201' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error that you're getting, you'll have to enable CORS on the servlet to allow accepting calls from other origins.

Just create a `private` method and call it from the methods where you're sending the actual response. You can set the `headers` in this method. Something like this:

```
private void setAccessControlHeaders(HttpServletResponse resp) {
  resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000");
  resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
}
```

---

> Source: [**Servlet - Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)**](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/java-servlet/servlet-cors.html)

Comment: Can you please update the question with the updated code that you tried? I'd also urge you to read through the source article once.